# Encrypt Windows 8 file history

Tags: windows, windows-8, backup, external-hard-drive, encryption

File history in Windows 8 is great, but it saves my files on an external drive without any encryption, and stores them using the exact same folder structure as the originals.

If a bad guy gets his hands on the hard drive, it could basically not be easier to get to my important files.

Is there any way to encrypt the file history backup without breaking its functionality and without having to encrypt the original content itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can even use BitLocker to encrypt the drive where you make the backup and access that drive from your computer, so that File History does its job regularly.

Comment: BitLocker is only on Professional editions of Windows though... I wonder what a home user can do?

Comment: Home users can upgrade to Pro through the Windows Store.

Answer (score 1):

If the external drive you are backing up to is NTFS you could use EFS, by right-clicking on as file choosing properties and then advanced, and set it to encrypted. Fat32 and other formats do not support EFS but you could use something like Truecrypt.

Answer (score 0):

You can [backup your data on a virtual hard disk file](https://www.slightfuture.com/how-to/file-history-network-storage) (VHD) with BitLocker, and store that file anywhere including hosted services and a local network drive. It’s very inefficient and will be slow, but you’ll get an encrypted backup using File History that can be stored anywhere and even copied to multiple locations.

Windows 10 may see some performance improvements here over Windows 8 as VHDs should be faster in 10 than 8.